# What is ActionMailer default_url_options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I must not understand something trivial about email but what does the host in defaul_url_options do? The need for the smtp settings make sense to me to configure how the email will be sent out but how is default_url_options relevant to that?

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = '<your heroku app>.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `default_url_options` setting is useful for constructing **link URLs in email templates**. Usually, the `:host`, i.e. the fully qualified name of the web server, is needed to be set up with this config option. It has nothing to do with *sending* emails, it only configures *displaying links* in the emails.

The need for setting this is nicely documented in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views) as well [`ActionMailer::Base` sources](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L113):

> URLs can be generated in mailer views using url_for or named routes. Unlike controllers from Action Pack, the mailer instance **doesn't have any context about the incoming request**, so you'll need to provide all of the details needed to generate a URL.
>
> When using url_for you'll need to provide the `:host`, `:controller`, and `:action:`
>
> ```
> <%= url_for(host: "example.com", controller: "welcome", action: "greeting") %>
> ```
>
> When using named routes you only need to supply the `:host`
>
> ```
> <%= users_url(host: "example.com") %>
> ```

So, to reword the docs, in web pages, the name of the current web server (to be used in absolute links) is taken from the incoming request info. But you don't have this information available when rendering an email (there's no request), that's why you have to provide it manually, so that links in emails work properly.

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever tried to generate URLs within an ActionMailer template? If you did at least once, then you are probably familiar with the following error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host])
```

This happens because ActionMailer instance doesn't have any context about the incoming request so you'll need to provide the :host, :controller, and :action:. If you use a named route, ActionPack provides controller and action names for you. Otherwise, with the url_for helper you need to pass all the parameters.

```
<%= message_url %>
<%= url_for :controller => "messages", :action => "index" %>
```

Regardless your choice, you always need to provide the host option to generate an URL in ActionMailer. As shown by the ActionMailer guide, you basically have two ways to pass the host value to ActionMailer:

```
1. set a global value
2. pass the option each time you generate an URL
```

**Defining default_url_options is better then passing URL everytime**.
That's why we do.